# Perforce Merge CLN across servers

Tags: perforce, branching-and-merging, perforce-integrate

**Problem :**

I have a strange requirement to move a specific CLN (Foo) from SERVER-1 to SERVER-2.

**Possible Solutions I can think of :**

Sol #1

- Create a patch of Foo in SERVER-1 to Foo.patch
- Apply the Foo.patch to SERVER-2

Sol #2

- Manually merge changes of "Foo" CLN from SERVER-1 to SERVER-2 ?

If anyone have faced a similar situation, Please provide the best recommendation.

Comment: Are you using "CLN" as a short-hand for "change list number"?

Answer (score 1):

If this will only be a one off act, then syncing the files from the original server, copying them to a workspace on the new server, then adding them with 'p4 add' is the easiest way of getting the files in to the new server.

The disadvantage with this method, is that the new server, won't have any details about the files history, before they were added.

If you do need to see details of the file history on the new server, please leave a comment.

Depending on your requirements there are a few possible solutions, so I do not want to elaborate on all of them in this answer.

Cheers,
Jen.